# Windows - Proxy settings for all users

Tags: windows, proxy

If I enable the following configuration on 'gpedit.msc', where do I set the proxy server address and port?

> Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows
>   Components\Internet Explorer\Make proxy settings per-machine (rather
>   than per user)

This is explained on this topic, but it doesn't make it clear:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms815135.aspx

If I enable this configuration and try running the following command as recommeded in other sources, nothing will be set and won't work as expected:

```
netsh winhttp import proxy source =ie﻿
```

The computer isn't an AD member and I can't add the GPO so it will be enabled for all users.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

What the GPO does is setting the value `ProxySettingsPerUser` of the registry key `HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`. Enabled is `0`, disabled is `1`.

Reference: [Make proxy settings per-machine (rather than per-user)](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.InternetExplorer::UserProxy)

Comment: Right, that I understand. My question is: where do I set the proxy server address and port so it affects all users? (so this previously mentioned policy makes any sense)

Comment: Do the same as I did for the `make proxy setting per-machine`. Lookup the Group Policy on getadmx.com and you'll find the registry key.

Answer (score 1):

```
Key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\  
Value: ProxyServer

Key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\  
Value: ProxyServer

String: [HostnameOrIP:Port]
```

Also see:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/askie/2017/06/20/what-is-defaultconnectionsettings-key/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to revive an old thread, but I figured this might help anyone looking for this answer. This stumped us for a couple days as well, but one of the answers pointed us in the right direction. The settings are stored as Binary in:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections

DefaultConnectionSettings 
SavedLegacySettings
```

To get the binary we needed I made the changes required and then did an export of the same settings under HKCU, edited the .reg file to point to HKLM, and then imported.

Hope this helps someone!